# Are relative dates available as data processor filters?

Tags: data-processor

Is there a way to set up the date filter options in Data Processor, so that they use the relative dates available in Civi?

(e.g: this week, previous quarter etc)

Can't see a way to do this at first look. Might make the resulting reports easier to use for some of my colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for use inside CiviCRM, I have found it better to just use «Field filter» for dates, instead of «Date filter». Then you get those options out of the box.

However, for usage with API calls, it is probably better with «Date filter», since then you can control the date format output.

Comment: I'll have a play with that in the next couple of days. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I feel like such a fool for not trying field filters.... 
thank you